# CSV string change with php

Tags: php, csv

Hi I would like to eliminate this sign " (quotation mark) in CSV file with PHP. I'm using this file with amchart, but with quotatnion mark chart doesn't work.

File is :
"date1,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,valu6,value7,value8,value9"

"date2,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,valu6,value7,value8,value9"

"date3,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,valu6,value7,value8,value9"

"date4,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,valu6,value7,value8,value9"

"date5,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,valu6,value7,value8,value9"

I'm using this code:

```
error_reporting(0);
$records = array_map('str_getcsv', file('http://localhost/projekt/file.csv'));
        $data =array();
        foreach($records as $row){
            if($row[0] != 'date'){
                $data[] = array(
            'date' => $row[0],
            'open'=> $row[1],
            'high'=> $row[2],
            'low'=> $row[3],
            'close'=> $row[4],
            'column-5'=> $row[5],
            'column-6'=> $row[6],
            'column-7'=> $row[7],
            'column-8'=> $row[8],
            'column-9'=> $row[9],
            'column-10'=> $row[10],
            'column-11'=> $row[11],
            'column-12'=> $row[12],
            'column-13'=> $row[13],
            );
        }
    }
    $chartdata = json_encode($data);

    $chartdata = str_replace('\/','/',$chartdata);
```

Comment: You cant use the `str_replace` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do a smaller change

```
 $records = array_map('str_getcsv',
    str_replace('"','',file('http://localhost/projekt/file.csv')));
```

Comment: I learned something new, str_replace works inside of an array!

Answer (score 2):

You can do with following statement:

```
array_map('str_getcsv', 
   array_map(
        function($item) {return trim($item, '""');},
        file('http://localhost/projekt/file.csv'))
);
```

Comment: That's amazing. Works very well!. Thanks